# Only one type of information is displayed in cell of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swift4

I want to display the information of "headlines" in viewDidload as cell, but it will be somewhat like an image. I would like to tell you the solution.

Specifically, I would like to display the information here in headlins, but only one piece of headlines information is displayed.

I did not know which part was the problem, so I filled out all the code.
If you do not understand the intent of the question, please let me know.

```
import UIKit

struct HeadLine {
  var date: Date
  var title: String
  var text: String
  var image: String
}

struct TableSection<SectionItem: Comparable&Hashable, RowItem>: Comparable {
  var sectionItem: SectionItem
  var rowItems: [RowItem]

  static func < (lhs: TableSection, rhs: TableSection) -> Bool {
    return lhs.sectionItem > rhs.sectionItem
  }


  static func == (lhs: TableSection, rhs: TableSection) -> Bool {
    return lhs.sectionItem == rhs.sectionItem
  }

  static func group(rowItems : [RowItem], by criteria : (RowItem) -> SectionItem ) -> [TableSection<SectionItem, RowItem>] {
    let groups = Dictionary(grouping: rowItems, by: criteria)
    return groups.map(TableSection.init(sectionItem:rowItems:)).sorted()
  }
}

fileprivate func parseDate(_ str: String) -> Date {
  let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
  dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
  return dateFormat.date(from: str)!
}

fileprivate func firstDayOfMonth(date: Date) -> Date {
  let calendar = Calendar.current
  let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
  return calendar.date(from: components)!
}

class testSectionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var testTableView: UITableView!

var headlines = [HeadLine]()

var sections = [TableSection<Date, HeadLine>]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    testTableView.delegate = self
    testTableView.dataSource = self

    headlines = [
        HeadLine(date: parseDate("2018-7-21"), title: "title1", text: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", image: "weight"),
        HeadLine(date: parseDate("2018-5-22"), title: "title2", text: "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", image: "user"),
        HeadLine(date: parseDate("2017-5-23"), title: "title3", text: "cccccccccccccccc", image: "lock"),
        HeadLine(date: parseDate("2018-5-24"), title: "title4", text: "dddddddddddddddd", image: "manager"),
        HeadLine(date: parseDate("2018-5-25"), title: "title5", text: "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee", image: "oka"),
        HeadLine(date: parseDate("2018-5-26"), title: "title6", text: "ffffffffffffffff", image: "omura"),
    ]

    self.sections = TableSection.group(rowItems: self.headlines, by: { (headline) in
        firstDayOfMonth(date: headline.date)
    })

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let section = self.sections[section]
    let date = section.sectionItem
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = " yyyy/MM/dd"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section = self.sections[section]
    return section.rowItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
    let headline = self.headlines[indexPath.item]
    cell.textLabel?.text = headline.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = headline.text
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: headline.image)

    return cell

}


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code in `cellForRowAt` the `sections` are not considered at all, so always the first headline (`title1`) is displayed.

Replace `cellForRowAt` with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
    let section = self.sections[indexPath.section]
    let headline = section.rowItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = headline.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = headline.text
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: headline.image)

    return cell

}
```

The *property* `headlines` is redundant.

Comment: Thank you !! It moved well !!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line
`let headline = self.headlines[indexPath.item]` 
to -> 
`let headline = self.sections[indexPath.section].rowItems[indexPath.row]`

check your full code each section only one headline item insert that's why show one item show in section.

Comment: Technically `row` and `item` are synonyms.